# How to store a reference to the class in php?

Tags: php, class

I would like to store a reference to a class, not a string. But I don't know, how is it possible in php.

```
class myClass { /* ... */ }

$mc = myClass; // ??

if($element instanceof $mc) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Change it to this: `$mc = new myClass();` and `$mc instanceof myClass`

Comment: You can't store reference to a class, you can store either class name as a string or reference to class object (instance of a class)

Comment: Does down voter care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [passing value by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) by using `&`.

Demo provided by the documentation:

```
<?php
function foo(&$var)
{
    $var++;
}

$a=5;
foo($a);
// $a is 6 here
?>
```

Similarly, you can create a new instance of a specific class and store it as a variable and reference that variable as a reference.